# How to call 20 webservices at same time in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my application I have a requirement to get the response before loading the tableview. I need to call around 20 API's at same time. And each API data need to show each 1 cell in tableview.

I need to call them in Viewdidload method which calls before tableview methods.

Can anyone guide or provide some useful example to do this?

Comment: You should read about GCD's dispatch_group. It's also available for swift.

Comment: do you use afnetworking library for json ?

Comment: That seems like a terrible API design. Any of those 20 requests can fail and most of the time one of them will fail.

Comment: Why not call a single service and get data for each cell ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal, its requirement to check whether api is working fine or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should use dispatch groups like this:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
networkCall1 {
    // response received
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
networkCall2 {
    // response received
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    // this will be notified only when there is no one left in the group
})
```

Before a network call you enter a group. When you receive a response you leave the group and when there is no one left in the group, `group.notify` block will execute.

This is just a simple explanation, you should read more about it to fully understand how it works.

Comment: Did you mean to declare `backgroundQ`? It isn't used in the rest of your code block

Comment: Right, I didn't use it in this example. I just copied my code from one project and it was there. It's used instead these `networkCallN`. Answer is updated and backgroundQ is removed.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use GCD's groups for that.

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosDefault)
let group = DispatchGroup()

var dataForTable:[String] = []
for number in 0..<n {
    group.enter()
    // Do your request with async callback, append data and leave GCD group.
    backgroundQueue.async(group: group, execute: {
        let newData = String()  
        dataForTable.append(newData)
        group.leave()
    })
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    print("All requests data")
    self.tableViewData = dataForTable
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```